# how to match date with in switch case in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$date1 = $_POST["txtMonth"];
$date2 = $_POST["txtYear"];

$monYear = $_POST["txtMonth"];
$dayMonYear = $_POST["txtMonth"];


switch(true)
{
case DATE_FORMAT("Y/m", $monYear):
MonthYear($monYear);
break;

case 'DD/MM/YYYY' == $dayMonYear:
DayMonthYear($dayMonYear);
break;

default:
ranges($date1, $date2);
}
```

how to match date within switch case. I am trying to get details from the database that should match with the date as I have different date formats like 
 this `yyyy/mm` and date range and `yyyy/mm/dd`. if I enter `2017/10/01` that should match in the case and if I enter `yyyy/mm` that should match in case.

Comment: what was the problem

Comment: I want to match input date in 'case' using date_format or any other. but the result is giving an error like     "date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface,"

Comment: why mysql  tag?  ..

Comment: I am Here entering the date and getting details from the database in excel. If I enter a date like yyyy/mm/dd that also should match in the case should return data.

Comment: I don't know PHP tag can you tell tag of PHP.

Comment: According to your code `$dayMonYear === $monYear`. And because of that I can't really see what the rest of the code is doing.

Comment: Yeah you are correct I want match with Number of input using date_format()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are going to have the /, you could

```
$date = explode('/',$date);
$count = count($date);
```

// this will check how many, than you can do a if = 3 variables or 2, you can check if it is 2 or 3 now with echoing $count. if it is month date, should be 2 otherwise if m/d/year, it will be 3, so this can check that, the next section will check which part of the array it is in.

```
foreach ($date as $role => $key){
 if (strlen($role) == 4)
{
$yearcheck = $key;
}
}
```

this one will check if it has 4 variables per one, then you will know which is the year.

Comment: This is how you parse data with expected parameters, 

since you know it will have a /
$date = explode('/',$date);
$count = count($date);
if ($count == 2){}

Comment: my date column name is dm_created_date I should match with that bro put your code switch.